# Oracle V$SESSION Machine is <ComputerName>\<ComputerName> instead of <Domain>/<ComputerName>

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I've a strange behavior with oracle and it's seems it causes problem with Security Policies.

When I look the V$Session table, some connection "MACHINE" are only the , other are <ComputerName> but I also have one which is <ComputerName>. And I've Security problems with this connection.
[image]

Do you have any idea why the MACHINE is `<ComputerName>\<ComputerName>` instead of `<Domain>/<ComputerName>` ?

Is there any way to fix this ?

The App "FicheTravail.exe" is running :

- .NetFramework 4.7.2
- EntityFramework 6.4.4
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.10.1
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 19.7.0

I'm simply using an oracle Connection string to connect to the database, without passing any info about the machine.

I'm sorry I don't give a lot of information but I don't really know what could help in this case.

Comment: That value is self-reported by the client machine, using whatever Oracle client libraries are appropriate. From the look of it, I'd say part of the difference is that some of your clients are using JDBC and others are using the OCI or Instant Client. There most likely isn't anything you can do to correct this.

Comment: You’ll need to change your security policies, the machine name a client tells Oracle about can be spoofed so shouldn’t play a part in it

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSayer, you're right but it's not my DB it's the customer's one. And they will not change the security policies. This is why I'm looking to fix things on my side. But it seems it will be complicated ^^